# How can I synchronize a callback code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have to get `description` in the `tmp` variable and I don't know how to synchronize this code, can someone help me ?

We want to render the contact user first_name in the calendar i.e. attach title to user.first_name. So We are grabbing all the events from the server, however for each event there are bookings and bookings contain the user id to grab the user data from contact_users. Then we need to construct the object and push it to array that has all the events namely `tmp`. The `callback` is called at the end to render the events in the calendar.

```
Event.query({
  businessId: $stateParams.businessId
})
.$promise.then(function(events) {
  events.forEach(function(event) {
    var tmpData = {};
    var description = '';
    $http.get('/businesses/'+event.business_id+'/events/'+event.id+'/bookings')
    .then(function(bookings) {
      if(bookings.data) {
        $http.get('/businesses/'+event.business_id+'/contact_users/'+bookings.data[0].people_id)
        .then(function(user) {
          description = user.data.first_name;
        });
      }
    });
    tmpData = {
      eventId: event.id,
      title: description,
      start: event.starts_at,
      end: event.ends_at,
      business_id: event.business_id,
      employment_id: event.employment_id,
      professional_id: event.professional_id,
      service_id: event.service_id,
    };
    tmp.push(tmpData);
  });
  return tmp;
}).then(function(result) {
  callback(tmp);
});
```

The callback is related to fullcalendar `callback` event fired in the `events` method.

Comment: You simply can't make an async operation suddenly be synchronous.  In Javascript, it cannot be done.  It looks like you're trying to use promises which is a good thing.  But, the execution is flawed.  You apparently have multiple `events` that you're trying to iterate through.  If you can describe in words what you're trying to accomplish with those events (use the edit link to edit your question), then we can likely help you fix this code.  But, please describe the desired result in words.  When you've edited the question address a comment to me here and I'll take a look.

Comment: I have made the edits, can you understand it ? I can describe more, really appreciate your help. @jfriend00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two key concepts when dealing with Promise callbacks:

**Returning a *value* from a Promise success callback causes causes the next promise to be resolved with this value.**

```
$q.when().then(function () {
    return 3;
}).then(function (result) {
    // result === 3
});
```

**Returning *another Promise* from a Promise success callback effectively replaces the existing Promise.**

```
$q.when().then(function () {
    return $timeout(function () { return 3 }, 1000);
}).then(function (result) {
    // called 1000ms later
    // result === 3
});
```

Additionally, there is a construct `$q.all(promises)` which takes an array of promises, and returns a new promise that is resolved when `promises` are all resolved (or when one of them is rejected).

---

I don't have access to your backend, so I could not test this, but something like this should work for you:

```
Event.query({ businessId: $stateParams.businessId }).$promise
  .then(function (events) {
    // get array of $HttpPromise objects
    var promises = events.map(function (event) {
      return $http.get('/businesses/' + event.business_id + '/events/' + event.id + '/bookings')
        .then(function (response) {
          var bookings = response.data;

          // "transformed" event object
          var evt = {
            eventId: event.id,
            title: '',
            start: event.starts_at,
            end: event.ends_at,
            business_id: event.business_id,
            employment_id: event.employment_id,
            professional_id: event.professional_id,
            service_id: event.service_id
          };

          // each promised is replaced either with a new $HttpPromise...
          if (bookings) {
            return $http.get('/businesses/' + event.business_id + '/contact_users/' + bookings[0].people_id)
              .then(function (response) {
                var user = response.data;

                evt.title = user.first_name;
                return evt;
              });
          }

          // ...or with an immediately resolved event
          return evt;
        })
    });

    // wait for all promises to be resolved
    return $q.all(promises);
  }).then(function (results) {
    // results is an array of transformed events
    callback(results);
  });
```

---

*Side note*: another option is to not wait for the inner `$http` promise to resolve, and simply return the "incomplete" `evt` object.

```
// launch a promise which updates evt when resolved
if (bookings) {
    $http.get('/businesses/' + event.business_id + '/contact_users/' + bookings[0].people_id)
        .then(function (response) {
            var user = response.data;

            // update evt reference
            evt.title = user.first_name;
        });
}

// immediately resolve with "incomplete" evt
return evt;
```

Angular triggers a digest every time a promise is resolved. Depending on how you set up your templates/rendering, this could have the effect of first rendering all events with an empty `title`, and then re-rendering with `first_name`s when they become available. Note that this this requires that you maintain `evt` references everywhere between your callback and your templates.

Comment: This works really good, except `title` is undefined for some reason.

Comment: Is `title` undefined or an empty string? Can you debug the callback to the inner `$http` promise? What is contained in the `user` variable?

Comment: Sorry mate @igorraush, I forgot to add `user.data.first_name`. You described everything exceptionally good. Thanks once again.

Comment: No problem! I also made an edit showing a slightly different approach which may be interesting to you. Also, it's a good idea in general to name the argument in `$HttpPromise` `then()` callbacks `response`. It is always a response object, in which the `data` property is the response body.

Comment: "*replaces the existing promise*" doesn't sound like the right phrase.

Comment: @Bergi you're right, it's not really correct. Returning a promise *A* from a callback causes the `then()` method to return a promise *B* which will be resolved with the value of *A* (after *A* is resolved). It's just a mouthful.